# Cygwin Rxvt issue

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, rxvt

With a recent version of CYGWIN (installed yesterday) on Windows 7, we are having a weird problem getting rxvt to work.

We used to use the following batch file:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

rxvt -fn 18x18 -bg black -fg white -g 85x55 -sr -e bash --login -i
```

To launch rxvt.  On our new machines, rxvt starts and immediately terminates.

Using the supplied cygwin shortcut (to lauch bash) and then executing the command:

```
rxvt -fn 18x18 -bg black -fg white -g 85x55 -sr -e bash --login -i
```

produces the right result, however.

Any ideas how to make a batch file that will launch rxvt properly?  What has changed that is leading to this script (which we have been using for years) to suddenly stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify '/bin/bash' instead of just 'bash'. Previous versions of Cygwin looked up an executable in the current directory if they couldn't find it in the PATH, but that was wrong for a Unix environment.